# Curve fitting algorithm from Klipfolio in python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, plotly-dash, klipfolio

I am looking for a way to apply such algorithm for curve fitting, that line does not exceed values from which it was fitter

Below there is python code with sample values, if you copy/paste it and run you will see that line on the right side is above points

```py
from scipy import interpolate
from numpy import linspace

y = [5, 0, 4, 4]
x = linspace(0, len(y)-1, num=len(y), endpoint=True)
f2 = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')
xnew = linspace(0, len(y)-1, num=100, endpoint=True)

plt.plot(xnew, f2(xnew), '--');
plt.scatter(x=[i for i in range(len(x))],y=y, color='red');
```

Comment: Could you provide an image of what you get and what exactly do you mean? I ran your code and am not sure what exactly is bothering you. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example based on your code comparing linear, quadratic and cubic interpolations. Only the linear interpolation is not above the right side data points. The only general method I know of for that purpose, other than linear interpolation, is clipping - which I personally would consider a bad practice.

[image: plot]

```
from scipy import interpolate
from numpy import linspace
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [5, 0, 4, 4]
x = linspace(0, len(y)-1, num=len(y), endpoint=True)
f1 = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='linear')
f2 = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='quadratic')
f3 = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')
xnew = linspace(0, len(y)-1, num=100, endpoint=True)

plt.title('Interpolation comparison')
plt.plot(xnew, f1(xnew), linestyle='solid', color='red', label='linear');
plt.plot(xnew, f2(xnew), linestyle='dashed', color='green', label='quadratic');
plt.plot(xnew, f3(xnew), linestyle='dashdot', color='blue', label='cubic');
plt.scatter(x=[i for i in range(len(x))],y=y, color='black');
plt.legend() # turn on the legend
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, quadratic looks much better but it is still a some kind of missguided for somebody who uses the chart, I will look for other solutions